# Convexity of $S=\left\{ \frac{\underline{x}^HA\underline{x}}{\underline{x}^H\underline{x}} , \underline{x} \in \mathbb C ^{n}\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

i've to prove that the following set is  convex:

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$

$$S=\left\{ \frac{\underline{x}^HA\underline{x}}{\underline{x}^H\underline{x}} , \underline{x} \in \mathbb C ^n\right\}$$

i've already tried to use the definition without success and then i tried to express every  $x \in S$ as a convex combination of some elements, without success too.

Can you help me?

Comment: A thought: it may help to write $A = P + Q$, where $P = P^H$ and $Q = -Q^H$.

Comment: You say $\underline{x}\in\mathbb C^n$, but later you say $x\in S$.  Could you clarify? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: When underlined i mean an element of $\mathbb C$ when not i mean an element of $S$, the vectors are used in the definition of $S$ but, as you can simply prove, $S$ is a scalar set so when later i say $x$ i mean something of the form $\frac{\underline{y}^HA\underline{y}}{\underline{y}^H\underline{y}}$. Is clear now?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171729/why-is-the-numerical-range-of-an-operator-convex

Comment: $S=\{ x^H A x|\ |x|=1\}$ right ?