# Showing convexity of a set in $\mathbb{C}^k$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert Space and $T\in\mathscr{B(\mathcal{H})}$. Suppose $$\mu_k(T):=\left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_1 \\
    \lambda_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    \lambda_k
    \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^k: PTP=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2 &\cdots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
    0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_k \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \text{ for some orthogonal projection $P$ of rank } k \right\}$$
**Is $\mu_k(T)$ convex in $\mathbb{C}^k$?**

---

Comments: I can only see that $\mu_k(T)$ is non-empty but I could not construct desired projection of rank k to show convexity of $\mu_k(T).$
Any hint/comment regarding convexity of $\mu_k(T)$ is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I don't know, but the spectrum needs not be convex. These sets look like a kind of spectrum so probably they are not convex as well.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, then $\mu_1(T)$ is the numerical range of $T$. Have you tried to immitate the convexity proof for the numerical range? Some references can be found in the comments to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171729/why-is-the-numerical-range-of-an-operator-convex

Comment: It's not clear how your set is defined. What's a matrix in $B(H)$? Do you want $PTP=\sum_j\lambda Q_j$ for fixed pairwise orthogonal rank-one projections, or for any such family of projections?

Comment: @MartinArgerami As $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space, we can think an operator $T$ on $\mathscr{B(\mathcal{H})}$ as a matrix of infinite order where (i,j)-th entry of that matrix is $\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle$ and $(e_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ being an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$. However one can think also the way you mentioned in the comment that $PTP=\sum_j\lambda_jQ_j$ where $Q_j$ are pairwise orthogonal rank one projection but $Q_j$ are dependent on $P$ i.e. for different $P$ we will get different $Q_j$'s.

Comment: @MaoWao In the proof of convexity of $W(T)$, it was boiled down to show numerical range of any 2-by-2 matrix is convex which was just computation. In the same line if we want to show $\mu_k(T)$ is convex, it is sufficient of proof $\mu_k(S)$ is convex where $S$ is compression of $T$ on union of $Ran(P_1)$ and $Ran(P_2)$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal projection obtained corresponding to two points of $\mu_k(T)$. After that I couldn't proceed to show $\mu_k(S)$ is convex like numerical range case.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: it looks like a numerical range, and those are usually convex.

Comment: Something seems off in your definition; if $P$ is a rank-$k$ projection (acting on $\mathcal H$) then $PTP\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ but the right-hand side is a matrix. I assume you want $P$ to be some sort of compression (?), i.e. for the standard basis $(\hat e_i)_{i=1}^k$ in $\mathbb C^k$ and an arbitrary orthonormal system $(e_i)_{i=1}^k$ in $\mathcal H$ define $$P:\mathbb C^k\to\mathcal H\quad \hat e_i\mapsto e_i$$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$ (plus linear extension onto all of $\mathbb C^k$). This way $P^\dagger TP\in\mathbb C^{k\times k}$ with fixed basis.

Comment: (2/2) In that case, the object in question is close to (but slightly more general than) [the rank-$k$ numerical range](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X08008135). Maybe this connection alone is of use to you already?